# nodejs setting object in req.session.data but not getting that data in next request?

Tags: node.js, session, express

i am setting the object in req.session.data,

```
 req.session.data = customObj;
 console.log(req.session.data);
```

it is showing the correct data in req.session.data

But in the next request, when i print session object data by

```
 console.log(req.session.data);
```

it is showing 'undefined'

I need that data in every next request.

how to resolve it?

Comment: as you definitely noticed console.log(req.session) prints out differnet thing than console.log(req.session.data); so could you please copy here what exactly is printed out when  console.log(req.session); is executed

Comment: For example CustomObj is customObj = { name : 'rajesh'}; when i print req.session, it shows { passport : {} , user : {userdata}, data : { name : 'rajesh'} },  but in next request, req.session.data is printing     "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, running

```
 req.session.save(function(err) {
        // session saved
    });
```

commits those changes and makes them accessible outside of the current scope - essentially forever, for that req.session.

I had the exact same issue and lucked into this by trial and error, and it should be noted **I'm not sure what other functionality might be implied by req.session.save.**

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you have not enabled a session store

Where you start your express app, ensure you have `app.use(express.session....`

eg:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'})); //can be any random value
```

More information: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions